# What does (char *) (&struct_var) do in C?

Tags: c

I am currently learning about 802.11 networks and in one of the tutorials, I came across this piece of code

```
send_len = sendto(sock_raw,(char *) &struct_var,64,0,(const struct sockaddr*)&sadr_ll,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
```

what is the purpose of typecasting struct var to char *?

Comment: Can you point to the tutorial? Is it old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object except bit-fields in C is constructed out of bytes. C 2018 clause 6.2.6 discusses the representations of types, and 6.2.6.1 2 says:

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
>   order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.

In other words, structures are manufactured for you by the C implementation. When you define and use a structure, the compiler builds it for you by laying out bytes and reading and writing various bytes according to the structure members you access.

This manufactured structure is not known to the network software. Network software just sends bytes back and forth. So, to send a structure, you let the network software send the individual bytes. It is up to receiving software on the other end to put the bytes together and use them as a structure, if it wants to do so.

Converting a pointer to a structure to a pointer to `char` is a way of showing that you want to treat the manufactured structure as the raw bytes it is composed of. In this case, the explicit cast is unnecessary because the function parameter is declared as `void *`, and the rules of C say that any pointer to an object may be implicitly converted to `void *`. In other words, you can just pass `&struct_var`, and the compiler will automatically convert it for you.

Comment: Commonly there is no machine code necessary at all for this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> What does (char *) (&struct_var) do in C?

The cast converts from one pointer type to a `char *`.

> what is the purpose of typecasting struct var to char *?

With `ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);`, the cast is not needed in C.  Any object pointer converts to a `void *` without a need to explicit casting.

Unless this is *old* code (different rules then pre 1989) or meant for a C and C++ compiler, the cast simply takes up space.